# PHP fopen not getting whole file

Tags: php, file

I'm trying to read a 3MB file in PHP. I use fopen to get the handle, and fread to read it. But when I call fread after reading ~1/2 the file, it stops reading, and my unpack function throws an error saying it got 0 bytes. Any ideas?

This is my binary reading function:

```
function binaryReadUShort($f){
      return unpack("S",fread($f,4))[1];
      }
```

And this is the code for reading the heightmap. $fh is the file handle.

```
  for($y = 0; $y < $size; $y++){
      for($x = 0; $x < $size; $x++){
        $height = binaryReadUShort($fh);
        $height = $height / 65535;
        $height = $height * 255;

        $color_alloc = imagecolorallocate($img,$height,$height,$height);
        imagesetpixel($img,$x,$y,$color_alloc);
      }
  }
```

Also, filesize()  returns the correct amount of bytes in the file, and I did a test, in which I counted the bytes I was reading. I confirmed I am NOT attempting to read past the end of the file.

Comment: How are you opening the file? Can you add that code to your question too?

Comment: `ReadUShort / fread(..,4)` - A short consisting of 4 bytes, are you absolutely positive about that?

Comment: try `Q` as the 1st `unpack` param?

Comment: @Thomas The function is called ReadUShort, It's unpacking a ushort and the file "seems" to contain only have of the expected elements. What is more likely: The wrong parameter in the unpack format or the wrong value for the parameter length in fread ? ;-)

Comment: @VolkerK - you should add an answer :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without further information I think the best guess is that you want to read 2-byte unsigned shorts ->

```
fread($f,2)
```

Comment: Wow I'm blind! That was it :P